# how was it to or how was it verb ing

Tags: gerunds

> How was it to work with him?

or

> How was it, working with him?

Are these both possible? I think the first one is better.
I searched on the internet but did not find any specific info. Both seem to be possible. Is there a difference in meaning? Maybe the second one is when you worked or have been working a long time with the person.

Comment: They're both possible, but in different contexts. Can you give us the full sentence and some context?

Comment: They're the same. And I wouldn't bother with the comma in the second

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the choice of gerund or infinitive, [this site](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/gerund-vs-infinitive-practice) offers some useful guidelines:

> **Gerunds** are often used when actions are real, fixed, or **completed**. "I enjoy cooking."
> **Infinitives** are often used when actions are unreal, abstract, or future: "He wants to swim."

In your sentence, you are talking about something that is **completed**, so a gerund is the best choice:

> How was it, working with him?

---

Note that, when you ask a question, you invert the subject and auxiliary verb/ be verb.

> It was good. - *statement*
> Was it good? - *question*
> Why was it good? - *question with question word*

So, for your question, it should be "How was it".